# Why is multiplication of operator not continuous in the strong operator topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a separable, infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space. How do we show that multiplication:
$$
\mathcal{L}(H) \times \mathcal{L}(H) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(H), \quad(A, B) \mapsto A B
$$
is not continuous with respect to the strong operator topology

So I want to clarify what it means for multiplication to be continuous in the first place. So if we have a sequence of operators $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$, then we should have that $lim A_nB_n \to AB$. So being not continuous, means this does not hold correct? Since we are working on a separable hilbert space, we can assume it is $l^2$. The only non-trivial linear bounded operator I know of on $l^2$ is just multiplication by a $l^\infty$ sequence. Now we are suppose to find a counterexample in the strong operator topology, which means we need two sequence of operators and some $x\in l^2$ where $||(A_nB_n - AB)x||$ does not converge to zero. Am I interpreting this problem correctly?

Comment: Note in particular the last paragraph of the answer while it is impossible to find *sequences* with the property from your question.

Comment: If $A_n\to A$ strongly and $B_n\to B$ strongly, then $A_nB_n\to AB$ strongly. But this is not sufficient for continuity with respect to strong operator topology.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate. Please see the other question for a couple answers.